# Segmentation fault using strcat

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, concatenation, strcat

Here is my code :

```
char *name, name_log="log-";
```

------getting 'name' from user-----

```
strcat(name_log, name);
char ext[] = ".log";
strcat(name_log, ext);
```

What i need to end up with is name_log = "log-'name'.log" but Im getting a segmentation fault error :((. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it ? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, if *this* is your code:

```
char *name, name_log="log-";
```

then `name_log` is a *char,* not a char pointer.

Assuming that's a typo, you cannot append to string literals like that. Modifications to string literals are undefined behaviour.

For a variable sized string, as `user` appears to be, probably the safest option is to allocate another string large enough to hold the result, something like:

```
char *name, *name_log = "log-", *ext = ".log";
// Do something to allocate and populate name
char *buffer = malloc (strlen (name_log) + strlen (name) + strlen (ext) + 1);
if (buffer == NULL) {
    // Out of memory.
} else {
    strcpy (buffer, name_log);
    strcat (buffer, name);
    strcat (buffer, ext);
    // Do something with buffer.
    free (buffer);
}
```

The `malloc` ensures you have enough space to do all the string operations safely, enough characters for the three components plus a null terminator.

Answer (score 3):

string literals get allocated a fixed amount of memory, generally in a read only section, you instead need to use a buffer.

```
char buffer[64] = "log-";
strncat(buffer,".log",32);
```

On a side note, `strcat` is generally unsafe, you need to use something that that checks the size of the buffer it uses or with limits on what it can concatenate, like `strncat`.

Comment: Bah! Wimp! `strcat` is only unsafe if you don't know the buffers are big enough. Real C programmers will point and laugh derisively at such a comment :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: true, but he is a beginner, not a real C programmer :P

Comment: `strncat()` is broken anyway, better to use `strlcat()`

Comment: @JeremyP: is that a standard function? cause tbh I never seen it before

Comment: @Necrolis: I thought it was Posix standard, but it appears it is not.  It is available on most Unixes though.

Answer (score 2):

A completely different solution would be this:

```
const char *prefix = "log-";
const char *suffix = ".log";
// There's a "char *name" somewhere
int size_needed;
char *result;

size_needed = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%s%s", prefix, name, suffix);
result = malloc(size_needed + 1);
snprintf(result, size_needed + 1, "%s%s%s", prefix, name, suffix);

// "result" now contains the desired string.
```

The nice thing about `snprintf` is that it returns the number of characters it would write if there was enough space. This can be used by measuring upfront how much memory to allocate which makes complicated and error-prone calculations unnecessary.

If you happen to be on a system with `asprintf`, it's even easier:

```
char *result = NULL /* in case asprintf fails */;
asprintf(&result, "log-%s.log", name);
// "result" must be released with "free"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to allcocate memory. You cannot add to a string in this way as the string added goes to memory which hasnt been allocated.

you can do

```
char[20] strarray;

strcat(strarray, "log-");
strcat(strarray, "abcd");
```

Comment: This, and in addition, `name_log` is of type `char` when declared like this. This should not even compile.

Comment: @Simon : actually i think its correct. I am eating my own words now. But the type is char* so i think it should be ok.

Comment: Please please please initialize the strarray to be an empty string (`strarray[0] = '\0'` or similar) before using it with strcat. (Or use strncpy instead of the first strcat).  Also please use strncat instead of strcat.

Comment: `char[20] strarray`? Don't you mean `char strarray[20]`?

Comment: @Sid Malani: No, Onica Radu is first creating a `*name` and then a `name_log`. The former is a pointer to char, the later is a char. Very common problem. It does compile, but it assigns the the *pointer value* of the string, casted to char. The compiler usually warns about assignment of pointer value to integer or something like that in this case.

Comment: ok cool. get it. Have been a while i messed around with c. I read it as char* a,b; so would have expected a and b both to be pointers to char.

Comment: This is the reason why people write `char *a` rather than `char* a`.

Answer (score 0):

the name_log is pointed at a static place: "log-", which means is could not be modified, while as the first parameter in `strcat()`, it must be modifiable.

try changing name_log's type `char*` into `char[]`, e.g.

```
char[20] name_log = "log-";
```

Comment: Why is everyone posting `char[20] str;` instead of `char str[20];`? Is this some new feature in C1x I haven't been made aware of? Or are your minds so rotted by Java that you don't know better? :-)