# Segmentation fault on strcat

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcat

I have recently begun working on learning the C language and have repeatedly run into an error in which calling the strcat function from the `<string.h>` module results in a segmentation fault.  I've searched for the answers online, including on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269199/segmentation-fault-using-strcat), without success.  I thought this community might have a more personal insight into the problem, as the general solutions don't seem to be working.  Might be user error, might be a personal issue with the code.  Take a look.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * deblank(const char str[]){
    char *new[strlen(str)];
    char *buffer = malloc(strlen(new)+1);
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(*str); i++){
        if(buffer!=NULL){
            if(str[i]!=" "){
                strcat(new,str[i]); //Segmentation fault
            }
        }
    }
    free(buffer);
    return new;
}

int main(void){
    char str[] = "This has spaces in it.";
    char new[strlen(str)];
    *new = deblank(str);
    puts(new);
}
```

I've placed a comment on the line I've traced the segmentation fault back to.  The following is some Java to make some sense out of this C code.

```
public class deblank {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String str = "This has space in it.";
        System.out.println(removeBlanks(str));
    }

    public static String removeBlanks(String str){
        String updated = "";
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            if(str.charAt(i)!=' '){
                updated+=str.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return updated;
    }
}
```

Any insights into this error will be much appreciated.  Please point out typos as well... I've been known to make them.  Thanks.

Comment: @WeatherVane Compiler warnings enabled. The `malloc(strlen(new)+1)` should allow that extra byte?

Comment: So what did the compiler say about `strlen(new)`? And about missing library header?

Comment: @Olaf not a good idea IMHO to remove the code that could clarify what this huge accumulation of weirdness should actually achieve ...

Comment: There are various erros, flaws and missconceptions in the code. All these will be covered by a beginner's C book. Please understand we are not a debugging/tutoring service. Read [ask]. Youtube videos or obscure blogs can't substitute a good textbook.

Comment: `if(str[i]!=" ")` will always be `true`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: It does not really help to understand what OP tries to achieve. OP should read a textbook and forget about Java when writing C code.

Comment: @WeatherVane No warning regarding it.  Only warning about implicit declaration of `malloc` for that line.  Note that I changed it to `strlen(*new)` to remove another warning on incompatible types.

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/jSCfBj)

Comment: Ah, so you *did* get warnings! Don't be surpised about crashing code if you ignore them.

Comment: @Olaf If you're smart, eager, generally programming experienced **and** masochistic enough, you **can** learn C from example code, man-pages, the standard and other online resources (BTDT) -- but I'd indeed recommend a good book as well. As for the code, I assume the java version at least did what was intended, so it might be helpful to understand **anything** here.

Comment: @FelixPalmen The Java worked properly.  Hence why I provided it.  My Java is much more sensible than my C...

Comment: @BrinBrody for starters, `char *new[strlen(str)];` defines an array of **pointers** to char, with the amount of pointers equal to the amount of characters in `str` (without the terminating `\0`) -- not what you want

Comment: @BrinBrody as the code continues to have such strange things, please don't take it as an offense, but, me too, I recommend you first learn some C basics from a book

Comment: @FelixPalmen Fixed it, no cigar.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thank you for the suggestion.  I'll look into it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I agree about learning by the standard. All other resources are to some degree incomplete, flawed or plain wrong (even the standard has some corrigenda). The problems greatly increase for blogs and youtube videos. I'd say by the latter you cannot really learn the language. (Man-pages are typically directly from the standard, but you have to know about the function to find them)

Comment: Declaring array `new` as an automatic (block-scope) variable does not cause its contents to be initialized.  Calling `strlen(new)` before assigning anything to `new` therefore produces undefined behavior.  Even after assigning contents, calling `strlen(new)` produces undefined behavior if there is not at least one null character (`'\0'`) among those contents.  Possibly you meant `sizeof(new)` instead.

Comment: Moreover, you should not return `new` from your function, nor any other pointer to automatic storage.  The lifetime of the pointed-to storage ends when the variable goes out of scope, and attempting to dereference the pointer afterward produces undefined behavior.

Comment: @JohnBollinger See solution.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `new` of type `char*[]`. So calling `strlen` is wrong anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `strcat` like you did, it is intended to catenate a C-string at the end of another given one. `str[i]` is a char not a C-string (remember that a C-string is a contiguous sequence of chars the last being the NUL byte).

You also cannot compare strings with standard comparison operators, if you really need to compare strings then there is a `strcmp` function for it. But you can compare chars with standard operators as char is just a kind of integer type.

This should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * deblank(const char str[]) {
    char *buffer = malloc(strlen(str)+1); // allocate space to contains as much char as in str, included ending NUL byte
    for (int i=0, j=0; i<strlen(str)+1; i++) { // for every char in str, included the ending NUL byte
      if (str[i]!=' ') { // if not blank
        buffer[j++] = str[i]; // copy
      }
    }
    return buffer; // return a newly constructed C-string
}

int main(void){
    char str[] = "This has spaces in it.";
    char *new = deblank(str);
    puts(new);
    free(new); // release the allocated memory
}
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, let's do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * deblank(const char str[]){
    char *new[strlen(str)];
```

^ This line creates an array of pointers, not a string.

```
    char *buffer = malloc(strlen(new)+1);
```

`malloc` is undeclared. Missing `#include <stdlib.h>`. Also, you should check for allocation failure here.

`strlen(new)` is a type error. `strlen` takes a `char *` but `new` is (or rather evaluates to) a `char **`.

```
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(*str); i++){
```

`strlen(*str)` is a type error. `strlen` takes a `char *` but `*str` is a `char` (i.e. a single character).

`i<strlen(...)` is questionable. `strlen` returns `size_t` (an unsigned type) whereas `i` is an `int` (signed, and possibly too small).

Calling `strlen` in a loop is inefficient because it has to walk the whole string to find the end.

```
        if(buffer!=NULL){
```

This is a weird place to check for allocation failure. Also, you don't use `buffer` anywhere, so why create/check it at all?

```
            if(str[i]!=" "){
```

`str[i]!=" "` is a type error. `str[i]` is a `char` whereas `" "` is (or rather evaluates to) a `char *`.

```
                strcat(new,str[i]); //Segmentation fault
```

This is a type error. `strcat` takes two strings (`char *`), but `new` is a `char **` and `str[i]` is a `char`. Also, the first argument to `strcat` must be a valid string but `new` is uninitialized.

```
            }
        }
    }
    free(buffer);
    return new;
```

`new` is a local array in this function. You're returning the address of its first element, which makes no sense: As soon as the function returns, all of its local variables are gone. You're returning an invalid pointer here.

Also, this is a type error: `deblank` is declared to return a `char *` but actually returns a `char **`.

```
}

int main(void){
    char str[] = "This has spaces in it.";
    char new[strlen(str)];
    *new = deblank(str);
```

This is a type error: `*new` is a `char` but `deblank` returns a `char *`.

```
    puts(new);
```

`puts` takes a string, but `new` is essentially garbage at this point.

```
}
```

Comment: Thanks?  This is more a breakdown of what's wrong, and less of a solution?

Comment: @BrinBrody Correct. You asked for "*Any insights into this error*", not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

So, not sure whether this helps you, but a C code doing the same as your Java code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *removeBlanks(const char *str)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if (!result) exit(1);
    const char *r = str;
    char *w = result;
    while (*r)
    {
        // copy each character except when it's a blank
        if (*r != ' ') *w++ = *r;
        ++r;
    }
    *w = 0; // terminate the result to be a string (0 byte)
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *str = "This has spaces in it.";
    char *new = removeBlanks(str);
    puts(new);
    free(new);
    return 0;
}
```

I would'nt recommend to name a variable `new` ... if you ever want to use C++, this is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I tried compiling with warnings enabled, here are some you should fix.

- You need to include `stdlib.h`
- `char *new[strlen(str)]` creates an array of `char*` not of `char`, so not really a string. Change it to `char new[strlen(str)]`.
- To check if `str[i]` is a space, you compare it to the space character `' '`, not a string whose only character is a space `" "`. So change it to `str[i]!=' '`
- `strcat` takes a string as the second argument and not a character, like you're giving it with `str[i]`.

Also, what are you using `buffer` for?

Another mistake, is that you probably assumed that uninitialized arrays take zero values. The `new` array has random values, not zero/null. `strcat` concatenates two strings, so it would try to put the string in its second argument at the end of the first argument `new`. The "end" of a string is the null character. The program searches `new` for the first null character it can find, and when it finds this null, it starts writing the second argument from there.

But because `new` is uninitialized, the program might not find a null character in `new`, and it would keep searching further than the length of `new`, `strlen(str)`, continuing the search in unallocated memory. That is probably what causes the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

There can be three approaches to the task.

The first one is to update the string "in place". In this case the function can look something like the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iso646.h>

char * deblank( char s[] )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( s[i] and not isblank( s[i] ) ) ++i;

    if ( s[i] )
    {
        size_t j = i++;
        do
        {
            if ( not isblank( s[i] ) ) s[j++] = s[i];
        } while( s[i++] );
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "This has spaces in it.";

    puts( s );

    puts( deblank( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
This has spaces in it.
Thishasspacesinit.
```

Another approach is to copy the source string in a destination character array skipping blanks.

In this case the function will have two parameters: the source array and the destination array. And the size of the destination array must be equal to the size of the source array because in general the source array can not have blanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iso646.h>

char * deblank( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *t = s1;

    do 
    {
        if ( not isblank( *s2 ) ) *t++ = *s2;
    } while ( *s2++ );

    return s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[] = "This has spaces in it.";
    char s2[sizeof( s1 )];

    puts( s1 );

    puts( deblank( s2, s1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output will be the same as shown above.

Pay attention to this declaration

```
char s2[sizeof( s1 )];
```

The size of the destination string in general should be not less than the size of the source string.

And at last the third approach is when inside the function there is created dynamically an array and pointer to the first element of the array is returned from the function.

In this case it is desirable at first to count the number of blanks in the source array that to allocated the destination array with the appropriate size.

To use the functions `malloc` and `free` you need to include the following header

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

The function can be implemented as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iso646.h>


char * deblank( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 1;   /* one byte reserved for the terminating zero character */

    for ( const char *t = s; *t; ++t )
    {
        if ( not isblank( *t ) ) ++n;
    }

    char *s2 = malloc( n );

    if ( s2 != NULL )
    {
        char *t = s2;       
        do 
        {
            if ( not isblank( *s ) ) *t++ = *s;
        } while ( *s++ );
    }

    return s2;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[] = "This has spaces in it.";
    char *s2 = deblank( s1 );

    puts( s1 );
    if ( s2 ) puts( s2 );

    free( s2 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as for the two previous programs.

As for the standard C function `strcat` then it cats two strings.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[12] = "Hello ";
    char *s2 = "World";

    puts( strcat( s1, s2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The destination array (in this case `s1`) must have enough space to be able to append a string.

There is another C function `strncat` in the C Standard that allows to append a single character to a string. For example the above program can be rewritten the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[12] = "Hello ";
    char *s2 = "World";

    for ( size_t i = 0; s2[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        strncat( s1, &s2[i], 1 );
    }

    puts( s1 );

    return 0;
}
```

But it is not efficient to use such an approach for your original task because each time when the function is called it has to find the terminating zero in the source string that to append a character.

Comment: "*In this case it is desirable at first to count the number of blanks in the source array that to allocated the destination array with the appropriate size.*" not always, this is a runtime vs memory consumption tradeoff. +1 for the most exhaustive answer possible ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can try recursively

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void deblank(const char* str, char *dest) {
    if (!*str) {*dest = '\0';return;}

    // when we encounter a space we skip
    if (*str == ' ') {
      deblank(str+1, dest);
      return;
    }

    *dest = *str;
    deblank(str+1, dest+1);
}

int main(void) {
    const char *str = "This has spaces in it.";
    char *output    = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    deblank(str, output);
    puts(output);
    free(output);
}
```

Comment: @chux ty, fixed it